# Can't center my navigation bar

Tags: navigation

I think something is wrong in my CSS code, but I can't figure out what.

The navigation bar is inside a container, and is divided into two sides (leftnav and rightnav) with a logo in the middle (center).

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

JSfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/JTXPr/

```
    <div class="container">
  <header>
      <div id="header">
        <ul class="leftnav">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
          </ul>
        <ul class="center">
            <li>
            <img class="headerimage" src="images/header.png" alt="Richi Rich Logo" />
            </li>
            </ul>
          <ul class="rightnav">
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end header-->
    </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: The fiddle you provided has broken markup. Fix that first and see if your problem persists

Comment: @DylanMadisetti 

Edit: I tided it up now but still not sure what's "broken". (Sorry, I'm quite new to all this). http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/JTXPr/1/

Comment: Had some mismatching tags was all. Closer inspection shows it wouldn't really make a difference for what you're trying to do. For "brokeness" check out http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 2):

Now I'm guessing you're looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/eGcLA/
I scrapped the majority of the code you were working with and instead of multiple unordered lists I used the pretty popular convention of HTML5 header and anchor tags.

```
 <header>
      <a href=""> Link </a>
      <a href=""> Link </a>
      <a href=""> Link </a>
 </header>
```

Simplicity is better. If you want the design to be responsive read about [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

Before you grab this code and run I'd like to point out a few things:

- The people on stackoverflow are awesome people, trying to help each other out. Pasting a bunch of code, most of which is illegible doesn't make us happy, and you don't learn from it yourself.
- Read a bit more. Just from what gave me, it seemed like you copied and pasted everything and anything to try to get your site to work. I'm not saying copy and pasting is a bad thing, but you should understand what you are copying and pasting.

A great place to start would be the [W3 consortium](http://www.w3.org/). Learn about the standards, learn what `Hypertext Markup` actually is and take it from there. I think it's great that you're trying and that's why I'm helping you out. But it's wrong to think that you should come to stackoverflow to do something that should be easy.